# Document ready function not working in nested html page : jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document-ready, jquery-load

I have a HTML page which having 1 div.

```
<div id="secondPage"></div>
```

and having

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("secondPage").load("mySecondHtmlPage.html")
})
</script>
```

This **mySecondHtmlPage.hmtl** is loading but I want to have another document ready function in that second html page, which is not firing.

When I have a jQuery reference in that page(second html) too documentReady function is getting fired but it is not loading properly inside the div.

**Second html page:**

```
<div>
 My Content  goes here
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
alert(''); //Not firing 
})
</script>
```

When I have a jQuery ref over top that alert is firing but it is not getting loaded in 1st html page.

Comment: are u included jquery library file?

Comment: Forget to add `#` in jquery where your load page `$("#secondPage").load("mySecondHtmlPage.html")`

Comment: Let's just be clear - you are mounting the second page to the document right? (Otherwise of course ready wouldn't fire.. just checking)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a different event once the page is loaded:

```
$( "#secondPage" ).load( "mySecondHtmlPage.html", function() {
    $(document).trigger('page-ready');
});
```

Then use this on the second page:

```
<div>
     My Content  goes here
</div>
<script>
    $(document).on('page-ready', function(){
        alert(''); //Not firing 
    });
</script>
```

Read more about `.trigger()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 0):

you should use **iframe** or **XMLHttpRequest**

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       // Action to be performed when the document is read;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Place all your javascript code from `mySecondHtmlPage.html` in the first page, or better detach the javascript from both pages in a expernal javascript file that you link to the first page